# Android - Dynamically Updating a custom ListView after items in an ArrayList are added

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have an activity that displays an initially populated custom ListView taken from an ArrayList, the user can then add to this list which I have no problem storing. I'm having problems displaying the added items. So far, the codes I see online use ArrayAdapter and they're only using the simple listView and not a custom one.

Here are the related files:

list_row_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/variant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="variant" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="quantity" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="221dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/quantity"
    android:text="unit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the part in my activity_order_form.xml that has the listView element.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewVariantB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
        android:text="Variant"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUnit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="123dp"
        android:text="Unit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewProductOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewVariantB" >

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the class where the ArrayList are stored.

```
public class CurrentOrderClass {

  private String productName;

  //ArrayLists
  private ArrayList<String> variantArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<String> unitArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


  //TODO ArrayList functions
  public ArrayList<String> getUnitArray() {
    return unitArray;
  }

  public void setUnitArray(ArrayList<String> unitArray) {
    this.unitArray = unitArray;
  }

  public void addToUnitArray(String unit){
    this.unitArray.add(unit);
  }



  public ArrayList<Integer> getQuantityArray() {
    return quantityArray;
  }

  public void setQuantityArray(ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray) {
    this.quantityArray = quantityArray;
  }

  public void addToQuantityArray(int quantity){
    this.quantityArray.add(quantity);
  }



  public ArrayList<String> getVariantArray() {
    return variantArray;
  }

  public void setVariantArray(ArrayList<String> variantArray) {
    this.variantArray = variantArray;
  }

  public void addToVariantArray(String variantArray){
    this.variantArray.add(variantArray);
  }
}
```

Here is the CustomListAdapter.java file

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> listData;

  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

  public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.variantView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.variant);
        holder.unitView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        holder.quantityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.variantView.setText(listData.get(position).getVariantArray().get(position).toString());
    holder.unitView.setText(listData.get(position).getUnitArray().get(position).toString());
    holder.quantityView.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getQuantityRow()));

    return convertView;
}

  static class ViewHolder {
    TextView variantView;
    TextView unitView;
    TextView quantityView;
  }


}
```

This is part of my OrderForm.java activity, this shows the onCreate and the method that populates the listView, as well as the part where user input is taken.

```
public class OrderForm extends Activity {

  public TextView tv;
  private int variantPosition; 
  CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
  CurrentOrderClass currentOrder = new CurrentOrderClass();

  @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_form);
          tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewProduct);

          //set variants here
          popolateItem();

          //set current order listview here
          ArrayList image_details = getListData();
          final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProductOrder);

          customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, image_details);
          lv1.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

  }

  private ArrayList getListData() {

          ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        currentOrder.getQuantityArray().add(i);
        currentOrder.getUnitArray().add("Sample text here." + i);
        currentOrder.getVariantArray().add("Another sample text here" + i);
        results.add(currentOrder);
          }
          return results;

  }

      //....snip snip excess code.....
      //This is the part wherein I add new items to the ArrayList in the class
      //After this, I'm not sure how to proceed


  currentOrder.setProductName(product.getName());
  currentOrder.addToQuantityArray(newQuantity);
  currentOrder.addToUnitArray(product.getUnit()[position]);
  currentOrder.addToVariantArray(product.getVariant()[variantPosition]);

  Log.d("Angelo", currentOrder.getProductName() + " " 
            + currentOrder.getQuantityArray() + " " 
            + currentOrder.getUnitArray() + " "
            + currentOrder.getVariantArray());


}
```

I also tried to place `customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the Log entry but nothing happened. Any ideas anyone? Thanks.

**EDIT AFTER ANSWERS AND MODIFICATIONS.**

Just follow FD's answer below and add the function he specified there and the 2 function calls after that. Now, you want to modify your `getListData()` function like this:

```
private ArrayList getListData() {

    ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

    int loopUntil;

    /* Two scenarios
     * First ---> the user started the activity for the first time, which means that the pre-populated list is what we want
     *            if this is the case, look at the else part of the boolean statement, it only loops until 10 
     *            and in addition, populates those elements
     * Second ---> the user has set something already and we want to populate until that element.
     * 
     */


    if(currentOrder.getQuantityArray().size() > 10){
        loopUntil = currentOrder.getQuantityArray().size();

        for(int i = 0; i < loopUntil; i++){
            currentOrder.getQuantityArray();
            currentOrder.getUnitArray();
            currentOrder.getVariantArray();
            results.add(currentOrder);
        }

    }
    else{
        loopUntil = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < loopUntil; i++){
            currentOrder.getQuantityArray().add(i);
            currentOrder.getUnitArray().add("Sample text here." + i);
            currentOrder.getVariantArray().add("Another sample text here" + i);
            results.add(currentOrder);
        }
    }

    return results;

}
```

The first condition executes when there is an item beyond the pre-populated one, since the else statement loops only until the pre-populated item (item number 9, index 0). This loop ensures that everything you add to the ArrayList gets added to the ListView.

The second condition executes when the activity is opened for the first time and there's supposed to be nothing in that list yet except the ones that you populated yourself.

Comment: I dont see where you passed your data to the adapter, unless im mistaken

Comment: post CustomListAdapter

Comment: Apologies for that blunder, edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your adapter does not get the new data, because you are initializing it with its own set of data.

One possibility would be to instantiate a new adapter and assign it to the ListView.

Add a field for your ListView in your activity:

```
public TextView tv;
private int variantPosition; 
CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
CurrentOrderClass currentOrder = new CurrentOrderClass();
ListView myListView; //Listview here
```

In onCreate, set myListView to point to your ListView:

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProductOrder)
myListView = lv1;
```

Finally, when you change your data, create a new Adapter for the new data:

```
myListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, getListData());
```

Alternatively, modify your Custom adapter to contain a setListData method:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> listData;

  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

  public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  public void setListData(ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> data){
    listData = data;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
  }


  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.variantView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.variant);
        holder.unitView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        holder.quantityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.variantView.setText(listData.get(position).getVariantArray().get(position).toString());
    holder.unitView.setText(listData.get(position).getUnitArray().get(position).toString());
    holder.quantityView.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getQuantityRow()));

    return convertView;
}

  static class ViewHolder {
    TextView variantView;
    TextView unitView;
    TextView quantityView;
  }


}
```

Then, after modifying your data, just call:

```
customListAdapter.setListData(getListData());
customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hmm. This seems like I'm "refreshing" the listView. What I want to do is to be able to add the user input to the listView directly and refresh the listView using `notifyDataSeChanged`. I also updated my question and it now contains my `CustomListAdapter` class.

Comment: `getListData()` only loops until the 10th item, I'll modify it and post the modifications I made in order to make the code work. I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: please answer this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46690220/6144372