# Append or prepend listView

Tags: java, android

How is best method to append or prepend ListView ?

A starting point is this tutorial.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-load-more-using-onscrolllistener-tutorial/

```
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, numberlist);
```

// Binds the Adapter to the ListView
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

But i think this method is reloading the list.

There are other ways of implementing or it would be best?

Comment: your `numberlist` is ArrayList or normal array?

Comment: numberlist is ArrayList

Comment: then you can add to list using `numberlist.add(yourObjects)` then call `adapter.notiftDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think thats the best way to pupulate listview and setAdapter is not for reloading the list that is to **Sets the data behind this ListView**

notiftDataSetChanged() method is to reload the list if you update the list.

one more thing if you want to use custome layout for your list then what your are doing is the best way but if you want to use default layout that android provides then

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);  
      // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I have a list of 100 results. In this list want to look for a method to add one or more elements at the beginning or end of the list.

Comment: How may refer to certain positions ?

Comment: if you want to do that then update your list and the call adapter.notifyDataSetCanged(); and it will update your list

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941054/android-dynamically-updating-a-custom-listview-after-items-in-an-arraylist-are this may help you

Comment: OK ... so the position is defined by the ArrayList that has to be updated?

Comment: my pleasure ... if your are satisfied w ith the answer kindly accept it

Comment: Note that ArrayAdapter has 'add' and 'addAll' methods similar to those of List, and allow for adding items dynamically to the ListView, without having to maintain a List yourself. You will still have to call notifyDataSetChanged afterwards.