# How to update a list item after it is added to the list?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a main list in which I am showing some options. In this I have one option of events which is added at 2nd index in main list. I have events arrayList and I get this list from asyncTask. So I get the Size of eventsArrayList in onPostExecute method.

But I need to show this count in item of main List. I tried to call prepareData method in onPstExceute after I get the size of an array. But it then takes much time to load show the main UI as it is connected  with the server.

So I thought to first show the eventArrayList size as 0 and the update the main list Item in onPostexecute method with the new size.

But this dose not change the count shown in the main list. I tried invalidate() on recyclerview still I could not refresh the recycler view.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,GetEventsAsyncTask.GetEvents {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private List<MainList> mainLists = new ArrayList<>();

    private String userUsername;

    public int PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE =10;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    ArrayList<Event> eventArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("username",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        userUsername = sharedpreferences.getString("UserUsername","No name defined");

        GetEventsAsyncTask getEventsAsyncTask = new GetEventsAsyncTask(this,MainActivity.this,eventArrayList);
        getEventsAsyncTask.execute(userUsername);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        eventArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


        prepareData();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MainListAdapter(mainLists, new MainListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(MainList item) {

                if(item.getTitle().equals("Plan Event")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlanEventActivity.class));
                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Events")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventsListActivity.class));
                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Photos")) {

                    photos = true;

                    checkFilePermissions();

                    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    permissionsAccepted = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("permission",false);

                    if(dir.exists()) {

                        listFile = dir.listFiles();

                        if (permissionsAccepted) {


                            if (listFile.length == 0) {


                                showAlert("No Images");

                            } else {

                                new MainActivity.SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, listFile[0]);
                            }

                      }
                        else {

                            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                            // functionality that depends on this permission.
                            showAlert("Please accept permissions to get access to photos.");

                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        showAlert("No Folder");
                    }

                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Reminders")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RemindersActivity.class));
                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Chat")) {

                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Notes")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotesActivity.class));
                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Notifications")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationsActivity.class));
                }
                if(item.getTitle().equals("Profile")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                }
            }
        }));

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    }

    private void prepareData() {


        MainList mainList = new MainList("Plan Event","", R.drawable.plan);
        mainLists.add(mainList);

        if(eventArrayList != null && eventArrayList.size() >= 0)
        {
            mainList = new MainList("Events",String.valueOf(eventArrayList.size()), R.drawable.events);
        }
        else
        {
            mainList = new MainList("Events", "0", R.drawable.events);

        }
        mainLists.add(mainList);


        listFile = dir.listFiles();

        if(listFile != null && listFile.length >= 0)
        {

            mainList = new MainList("Photos", String.valueOf(listFile.length), R.drawable.phone);
        }
        else
        {
            mainList = new MainList("Photos", "0", R.drawable.phone);
        }

        mainLists.add(mainList);

        mainList = new MainList("Reminders","20", R.drawable.remind);
        mainLists.add(mainList);

        mainList = new MainList("Chat","2", R.drawable.chat);
        mainLists.add(mainList);

        mainList = new MainList("Notes","2", R.drawable.notes);
        mainLists.add(mainList);

        mainList = new MainList("Notifications","20", R.drawable.remind);
        mainLists.add(mainList);

        mainList = new MainList("Profile","50%", R.drawable.user);
        mainLists.add(mainList);

    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Event> response) {

        eventArrayList = response;

        MainList mainList = new MainList("Events","eventArrayList.size()", R.drawable.events);

        mainLists.set(2,mainList);

        recyclerView.invalidate();

    }
}
```

What to do? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941054/android-dynamically-updating-a-custom-listview-after-items-in-an-arraylist-are

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create the `MainListAdapter` as a private field in the class instead of add it as anonymous class during recyclerview's `setAdapter()` call.

Indeed, in `onPostExecute()` callback, you have to call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating `mainLists` variable.

Comment: @user6265109 did the answer help?